# Populate Drop Down Menus Through PHP From MySql

Tags: mysql, html, drop-down-menu

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I have a MySql database containing several tables. My question revolves around the use of data from three of these, 'userdetails', 'detectors' and 'searchheads'.

What I would like to do is to populate a drop down menu on my HTML form that shows the 'detectors' that are user specific and, in turn, another drop down menu that again is user specific but also only shows the 'searchhead' applicable to the 'detector' selection made in the first drop down menu.

All three tables have a 'userid' field and the tables for the 'detectors' and 'search heads' have a 'detectorid' field.

Could someone perhaps please show me how I would go about setting this up because I must admit I haven't a clue where to start.

Many thanks and regards

Chris.

**UPDATED JS CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){     
            $.fetch_data    = function (what) {         
            var send    = {             
            "what"  : what,             
            "data"  : $("select[name=detectors]").val()         
            };         
            $.post ("dropdownmenus.php", send, function(data){             
            $("select[name=" + what + "]").html(data);         
            });     
            };     
            $.fetch_data ("detectors");     
            $("select[name=detectors]").live("change", function(){         
            // reset the searchhead as new data will be implemented         
            $("select[name=detectorsearchheads]").html("");         
            $.fetch_data ("detectorsearchhead");     
            }); 
            }); 
        </script>
```

**UPDATED PHP CODE**

```
<?php     
$request    = array (        
"detector"      => @$_POST["detector"],         
"detector"      => @$_POST["detector"]     );     
// clean $request.     
$build_query    = "select * from " . $request["what"] . " "                     
. "where userid = \"" . $user_id . "\"";    
$build_results  = mysql_query ($build_query);     
$return_results = "";     
foreach ($build_results as $index => $data) {         
$return_results .= "<option value=\"detector" . $data["id"] . "\">" . $data["text"] . 
"</option>";     }     
echo $return_results; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more Javascript than complex MySQL queries.

**form.php**

This page is where your form is located. I have created an Ajax function which grabs necessary data. I haven't completed everything but I gave you an outline of what you need to complete. The data collected from the `select` inputs are transferred via an ajax `post` request in jQuery. The data is then manipulated and formatted into html data which can be understood by the `select` input.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fetch_data    = function (what) {
        var send    = {
            "what"  : what,
            "data"  : $("select[name=detectors]").val()
        };
        $.post ("url/to/ajax.php", send, functio(data){
            $("select[name=" + what + "]").html(data);
        });
    };
    $.fetch_data ("detectors");
    $("select[name=detectors]").live("change", function(){
        // reset the searchhead as new data will be implemented
        $("select[name=searchhead]").html("");
        $.fetch_data ("searchhead");
    });
});
</script>
<form>
    <label>Detectors</label>
    <select name="detectors">

    </select>
    <label>Search Heads</label>
    <select name="searchead">

    </select>
</form>
```

**url/to/ajax.php**

Here you will have to make adjustments to how your data is manipulated. You could use a PHP `switch` depending on the `what` variable, which would change the query depending on what's requested.

```
<?php
    $request        = array (
        "what"      => @$_POST["what"],
        "data"      => @$_POST["data"]
    );
    // clean $request.
    $build_query    = "select * from " . $request["what"] . " "
                    . "where userid = \"" . $user_id . "\"";
    $build_results  = mysql_query ($build_query);
    $return_results = "";
    foreach ($build_results as $index => $data) {
        $reurn_results .= "<option value=\"" . $data["id"] . "\">" . $data["text"] . "</option>";
    }
    echo $return_results;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, this is absolutely brilliant. Many thanks for spending time in replying and for all the work you've done to help me on my way. I'll have a go at this and let you know how I get on. Regards Chris

Comment: Hi, you'll have to forgive me and my lack of experience around this, but I must admit to clutching at straws into what I should be changing. I have made some changes, albeit minor which I've posted as an update in my original post. Could you perhaps explain what the parts of the coding do if that's at all possible just so i know what to do. Many thanks and regards

Comment: Not a big fan of loading static parts of the page at runtime. You're not only slowing down your site, but the user is treated with empty select boxes that slowly fill in. Plus search engines don't run javascript so they'll never see that content (same goes for users with javascript disabled).