# PHP Drop Down Menus

Tags: php, html

I wonder whether someone may be able to help.

I posted [a similar message to this little three days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928568/populate-drop-down-menus-through-php-from-mysql), but I think that my explanation of the problem wasn't particualrly good so I thought I'd start afresh. I will say that I am new to programming in PHP so please bear with me.

I have three mySQL tables, 'userdetails', 'detectors' and 'detectorsearchheads' with the following fields:

**userdetails**

- userid
- name

**detectors**

- userid
- detectorid
- detectordescription

**detectorsearchheads**

- userid
- detectorid
- detectorsearchheadid
- detectorsearchheaddescription

What I would like is to have a drop down menu on my HTML form that through PHP, shows the list of detectors applicable to the user that is logged on. In turn I would then like another drop down menu that again is user specifc, but additionally only shows the detector search heads applicable to the value selected from the first drop down menu.

I appreciate that there may be other ways to do this but I am more comfortable with PHP.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly please show me what I need to do to get this to work. As I said earlier I am fairly new to PHP, so the simpler the better.

Many thanks and regards

Chris

**UPDATED CODE**

```
  <?php
                        mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die("Connection Failed");
                        mysql_select_db("databasename")or die("Connection Failed");
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM detectors WHERE `userid` = '1' ORDER BY 'detectorname' ASC";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        ?>
                        <select name="detectorname">
                            <?php
                            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $line['detectorname'];?>"> <?php echo $line['detectorname'];?> </option>

                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
```

Comment: Why is there a `userid` column in `detectorsearchheads`, won't that always be the same as the corresponding `userid` field in `detectors`?

Comment: What is the part that hinders you most to finish your task? Is it to refresh the second dropdown when the first was changed?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [tutorial](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-css-example-dropdown-menu/) for example.

Before that you have to generate the html and js code with php. Basicly, get the data from database, and generate needed list. For example:

```
echo "<li>".$dataFromDatabase."</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need CSS/JS to display the Drop Down Menu. With PHP you will prepare the text to be displayed.
After the mysql query, the result should be echoed in appropriate format.
For Eg. if your CSS displays **list items**(li) as menu, you need to do what 'Waltsu' said.

```
$result = mysql_query("..."); //your specific query
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<li>'.$row['detectordescription'].'</li>';
    //so on
}
```

Comment: All, sincere thanks for taking the time to look and reply to my post. EdoDoDo , yes you are quite right in that the userid will be the same in all the tables. Through lack of experience I assumed I would need this in all of them. I've done quite a bit of programming in MS Access, so I suppose, incorrectly I look at how I would complete this in Access. hakre, all I really would like is a really simple step by step guide what I need to do. I think from a beginners perspective it's difficult when trawling the web to know what is the best solution for your needs. Once again all many thanks. Chris

Comment: Hi, I've been working on the code for this over the last couple of days and I've managed to get my first drop down box to work. I've added the code as an update to my original post. What I'm not sure about now, is how to base the list of the second menu from the selection made from the first. I'd like to be able to only show those values in the 'searchheads' menu where the 'detectorid' matches that from the selection made in the first(detectors) drop down menu. I just wondered whether somoene could possibly please tell me how I would go about doing this. Many thanks Chris

Comment: All, I've fixed this problem by using an AJAX script. Many thanks for all your help. Kind regards. Chris